# How to restart linked Docker Compose services in PyCharm's Run Configuration?

Tags: python, docker, configuration, pycharm

I'm trying to use a Django server run/debug configuration in PyCharm with a [docker compose interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) and the 'backend' service. Everything works fine, however when I restart the server, only one container ('backend') is restarted:

```
xxxxx_redis is up-to-date
xxxxx_frontend_1 is up-to-date
xxxxx_postgresql is up-to-date
xxxxx_celery_1 is up-to-date
Starting xxxxx_backend_1 ...
```

How can I make some linked services (e.g. 'celery') restart as well via PyCharm? The definition of 'backend' looks like this:

```
backend:
  build:
    # build args
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=<settings.module>
  user: root
  volumes:
    # volumes definition
  links:
   - postgresql
   - redis
   - frontend
   - celery
```

Comment: What does the full docker-compose.yaml configuration look like? And can you include a screenshot of your Run Configuration?

Comment: @Rach Sharp: I've found a simple solution (check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584493/244297) below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding the name of the service to the end of the default `up` command in **Command and options** did the trick for me:

[image: Run Configuration]

Now both `backend` and `celery` are restarted when I run the configuration.